# sql query to split day part from time period

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to get last day result from my hit table.
last day means if i run query at 7 am in 28/10/2013 , it should return the result of between 
00h:27/10/2013 and 24h:27/10/2013 .

here is my query :

```
SELECT  COUNT(ID) FROM [tblHit] AS V WHERE  HitDate between
DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))  and  convert(date, GETDATE())
```

is this query get the result?

the only thing that bother me is that if i check between to

```
convert(date, GETDATE())
```

the hour gets included too and result goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @Yesterday date = DateAdd(day, -1, Getdate())

SELECT  COUNT(ID) FROM [tblHit] AS V 
WHERE  HitDate >= @Yesterday and HitDate < DateAdd(day, 1, @Yesterday)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you mean by 'last day'

If you mean you want to select records for yesterday then you can do

```
 Select *
 From tblHit
 Where cast(hit_date as date) = dateadd(d, -1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

If you mean you want the latest day's records then you can use `DENSE_RANK()`

```
Select *
From (
    Select *,  dense_rank() over (order by cast(hit_date as date) desc) dr
    From tblHit
) t
Where dr=1
```

If you mean you want the second latest day's records then again using `DENSE_RANK()` simply change the criteria slightly

```
Select *
From (
    Select *,  dense_rank() over (order by cast(hit_date as date) desc) dr
    From tblHit
) t
Where dr=2
```

Comment: I have no idea how this query even comes close to addressing the question.

Comment: I wasnt sure what the op meant by 'last day', have edited with some explanation of answer.